# If $f:G\rightarrow G'$ is a homomorphism, then prove $f^{-1}(H')$, where $H' < G'$, is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

If $f:G\rightarrow G'$ is a homomorphism, then prove $f^{-1}(H')$, where $H' < G'$, is a subgroup of $G$

Attempt: Let $K = f^{-1}(H')$. We want to prove that $K < G.$ Because $H'$ is a subgroup of $G'$, then $e_{G^{\,'}}\in H'\implies e_G\in K.$ For inverses, we have that becuase $H'<G'$, $g\in G'\implies g^{-1} \in G'\implies f^{-1}(g^{-1})=(f^{-1}(g))^{-1}\in K.$ For associativity, because $K \subseteq G,$ $K$ is associative. But how do you prove closure of $K$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g_1,g_2 \in f^{-1}(H')$, then $f(g_1),f(g_2) \in H'$. Then $f(g_1 g_2) = f(g_1) f(g_2) \in H'$ as well, so $g_1 g_2 \in f^{-1}(H')$.

Comment: How do you go from step 1 to 2? Doesn't f have to be injective for that?

Comment: @LaplacianFourier I did not claim "$f(g_1) \ne f(g_2)$ if $g_1 \ne g_2$." It's just saying that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are in the preimage $f^{-1}(H')$ (i.e., the set of elements of $G$ that $f$ sends to $H'$), so by definition $f(g_1)$ and $f(g_2)$ are in $H'$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g_1,g_2 \in f^{-1}(H)$ then $f(g_1),f(g_2) \in H $.

Since $f$ is homomorphism and $H$ is subgroup, $f(g_1)f(g_2)=f(g_1g_2)\in H$.

So $g_1g_2 \in f^{-1}(H)$.

Comment: See comment to previous answer please

Comment: $f^{-1}(H) = \{ x \in G : f(x) \in H\}$.